# using keras_cv model in opencv is possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, keras-cv

I trained object detection model in keras_cv like this https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet and like this https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8.
Next i converted model to frozen graph like this

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(path, file))

# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
                tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()

# Save frozen graph from frozen ConcreteFunction to hard drive
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir=path_res,
                  name=file.split('.')[0]+".pb",
                  as_text=False)
```

I try load this frozen graph like this
`tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('model.pb')`
and recive error:
`[ERROR:0@1.743] global tf_importer.cpp:3171 parseNode DNN/TF: Can't parse layer for node='yolov8_detector_2/tf.repeat_11/Repeat/Reshape' of type='Reshape'. Exception: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_graph_simplifier.cpp:902: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !field.empty() in function 'getTensorContentRef_'` 
What i do wrong?

P.s.: i completely did this way with classification keras model, but with keras_cv objectdetection model i cannot do this... Please help me!

I try find example in google

Comment: that thing is just named "keras cv". there is no implied compatibility with OpenCV. if you want to use a model, store it in a compatible file format. even then, some layer types may not be supported.

Comment: The question is how to use the keras cv model in production without installing tensorflow and keras. For example, using opencv or onnx. I need instructions or a link to an example. All training articles for inference use the same model that has just been trained directly in the keras framework through the prediction method.